# Overlapping legend: How to put geopandas legend next to the map?

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

I am using `geopandas` and `contextily` to plot building data (polygon) from OpenStreetMap. The problem is, the legend is overlapping the map. **Is there any way to put the legend next to the map?** or plot the map without legend, but export the legend separately from the map?

I hope the image helps.

here's my code to produce the map (I know the code is a little different, but it yields the same map):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
%matplotlib inline

buildings = gpd.read_file("buildings.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9,9))
buildings.to_crs(epsg=3857).plot(column='building', ax=ax, cmap="Paired", legend=True)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldTopoMap)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `legend_kwds` and `bbox_to_anchor` positioning within that. You may want to fiddle with the actual values.

```
buildings = gpd.read_file("buildings.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(9,9))
buildings.to_crs(epsg=3857).plot(column='building', ax=ax, cmap="Paired", legend=True, legend_kwds={'bbox_to_anchor': (1.3, 1)})
ctx.add_basemap(ax, url=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldTopoMap)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```